# Defining django queryset with Q objects with foreign key

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

Example model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()

class Author(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and some example data:

```
Book:
id  title
1   test111
2   test222
3   test333
4   test444

Author:
book_id  name
1        test111
1        test222
2        test222
2        test333
3        test111
3        test333
4        test111
4        test333
```

I want get all books which authors name contains '111' and '333' (so all books which have at least 2 authors: first with 111 in name, second with 333 in name)

I can reach this goal by using chain query:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(author__name__icontains="111").filter(author__name__icontains="333")
```

which return two books with id: 3 and 4

**Is there any way to reach above goal by using Q objects?**

Comment: Here the model `Book` doesn't have a foreign key to the model `Author`. Then how can you filter using author name?

Comment: When call Book.objects.filter(author__name__icontains="111") on shell, django call sql query with INNER JOIN on (book.id = author.book_id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine reduce and Q, see [The power of django’s Q objects](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/) post.

```
from django.db.models import Q
import operator
auths = [ "111", "333" ]
query = reduce(operator.and_, [ Q(author__name__icontains=x) for x in auths ] )
books = Book.objects.filter( query )
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is for dynamic auth list:

```
pk_list = qs.values_list('pk', flat=True)  # i.e [] or [1, 2, 3]

if len(pk_list) == 0:
    Book.objects.none()

else:
    q = None
    for pk in pk_list:
        if q is None:
            q = Q(pk=pk)
        else:
            q = q | Q(pk=pk)

    Book.objects.filter(q)
```